Specific feed is being automatically removed when added to a specific chatroom
In Code Golf's main chatroom, The Nineteenth Byte, we used to have a feed posting new challenges from our sister site Code Golf Codidact, specifically the RSS feed https://codegolf.codidact.com/categories/49/feed.rss. Up until a month or two ago, this worked, but somewhere between June 30th (the last feed message) and July 5th (the earliest codidact challenge after that), the feed randomly disappeared, with no chat message announcing this as there would be if a user removed it.
Attempting to re-add this feed specifically to this room results in the feed disappearing with no notice around 15-30 seconds later. Something resembling this does seem to have been reported almost a decade ago.

Now you see it

Now you don't
In particular:

Adding this feed specifically to TNB results in it being randomly deleted. This doesn't seem to apply to other rooms created for testing purposes, or even other main site chatrooms like The Garbage Collector.
Only directly adding this feed causes issues - taking an existing feed and editing it to the above URL succeeds. However, this doesn't correctly format the title of the feed - top is the added-and-soon-to-be-removed feed, bottom is the edited feed. .
It seems to be specifically this URL - The URL https://codegolf.codidact.com, along with other invalid RSS feeds / valid RSS feeds, don't exhibit this behaviour. It's possible that there's some specific issue with this specific RSS feed causing it to be removed, but nowhere is any behaviour resembling this documented.


Update: Thanks ArtOfCode for unblocking us!
Turns out life on the internet mostly consists of dealing with Cloudflare blocks these days.
Yes, I'm astutely aware of the irony 
Original post follows:


After a feed has failed to work 50 times in a row, it gets (soft-)deleted. If you add the same feed URL back to the same room, the feed is re-enabled, but the failure counter isn't reset until there has actually been a successful fetch of the feed.
And thus, after re-adding, if the next fetch attempt (which will happen within a minute) fails again, it'll immediately be deleted again, because the counter is still over fifty.
And alas, it keeps failing:
chat.stackexchange.com
Room 240: https://codegolf.codidact.com/categories/49/feed.rss
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
fifty failures in a row; disabling this feed

It works fine when I try it in my local instance of Chat, but it fails in production. Unfortunately it looks like Codidact has IP blocked our web tier 
(To be clear, I don't know this for a fact -- it just seems to be the obvious conclusion.)

Taken note of on Codidact. Hopefully will get solved in not too long, if the issue is there.

Our IP blocks don't return 403s, so that's not what's happened here but I'm not sure what is. I'll have a dig into the logs.

@ArtOfCode Hmm ok, thanks. Let me know if I can assist. I'm also in the Tavern and TNB right now.

We fixed it - blame Cloudflare!

Is cloudflare the new blame caching now? :D

@JourneymanGeek At the heart of it, CF is a giant cache with an attitude. So that seems right
